# accessing user attributes with a has_many and belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, associations

Not sure why i can figure this out but would appreciate some assistance. I am trying to access the attribute name from my user model when displaying search results using ransack.

My recipe controller is like so

```
def index
  @q = Recipe.search(params[:q])
  @searchresults = @q.result(:distinct => true)
  @q.build_condition
end

def search
  index
end
```

so when i output the results in my search page i can select attributes from the recipe model but cant get anything returned from the user model (I guess this has to do with the fact that in my index i have Recipe.search ? )

View

```
<% @searchresults.each do |r| %>
  <%= image_tag r.avatar.url(:thumb)%>
  <%= r.user.name%>
  <%= r.dish_name %>
  <%= r.difficulty %>
  <%= r.preperation_time %>
<% end %>
```

I get undefined method name with this

Recipe model

```
belongs_to :user
```

User Model

```
has_many :recipes
```

What am i missing, something simple im guessing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't want to chain association methods together, as it makes dealing with `nil` associations much more difficult (I assume that's what is happening here: `r.user` is `nil`, and `nil.name` is an undefined method).

Rails has a built-in delegator you can use to sidestep this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, :to => :user, :prefix => :user, :allow_nil => true
end
```

This will define a recipe instance method called `r.user_name` which returns the name if the user exists and `nil` if it doesn't.

Comment: Well im slightly confused as the name is taken when the user signs up and they have to fill it in....ah unless one of my older users uploaded a recipe when there wasnt a username field when signing up. Would that casue an issue if one or 2 recipes didnt have a name?